# Indicator functions, mean value, unclear property

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, means

I have an easy question about indicator functions.

Let $A$ be any event. We can write $\Bbb P(A)$ as an expectation, as
 follows:

Define the indicator function:

$$ I_A = \begin{cases} 1,  & \text{if event $A$ occurs} \\ 
0, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

Then $I_A$ is a random variable. **Why** the first and last euality holds here:

$$ \Bbb E(I_A) = \sum_{r=0}^1  r \cdot \Bbb P(I_A = r) \\
 = \Bbb P(A). $$

?

Comment: The left equality is the definition of the expectation of $I_A$. The right inequality follows from a simplification and the definition of $I_A$.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I'm a beginner. What simplification do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general if $X$ is a random variable with $\mathsf P(X\in S)=1$ where $S$ denotes a countable set then: $$\mathsf EX=\sum_{s\in S}s\mathsf P(X=s)$$

Observe that $\mathsf P(1_A\in\{0,1\})=1$ and apply that to find the first equality.

---

$\mathsf P(X=1)$ is just an abbreviation of $\mathsf P(\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)=1\})$.

For $X=1_A$ we find: $$\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)=1\}=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid 1_A(\omega)=1\}=A$$ so that: $$\mathsf P(1_A=1)=\mathsf P(A)$$

Answer (score 2):

$r$ can take on two values, when $r=0$ the term vanishes, and when $r=1$ it takes on $P(I_A = 1) = P(A)$

Comment: But why technically $P(I_A = 1) = P(A)$?

Comment: @user122424 what does $I_A$ mean? it is an indicator function for the event $A$. So what that means is that if $A$ occurs, $I_A=1$, if it doesn't occur, then $I_A=0$. Now, $P(I_A=1) = $ probability that the indicator of the event A is 1 = probability that the event A happens = $p(A)$